# Disable locale for NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using an `NSNumberFormatter` with the format of "##,##0.00", but my locale is set to the region of South Africa which uses a currency format like "## ##0.0", is there a way for me to disable `NSNumberFormatter` from using a locale, and to use specifically what i've typed in for the format? i've tried just going:

```
formatter.locale = nil;
```

and

```
formatter.formatterBehavior = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
```

some output from my program:

format = #,##0.00

result = -8 933 434,38

there is a variable

```
formatter.localizesFormat = NO;
```

but that is only for OS X

A server is going to tell me what number format to use, and needs to override what the user has set their region to.

relevant code:

```
self.amountFormat = @"##,##0.00";

NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSLog(@"self.amountFormat = %@", amountFormat);
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setPositiveFormat: self.amountFormat];
[formatter setLenient:YES];

NSNumber* newNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: [number doubleValue] / 100.0];

NSString* numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber: newNumber];

NSLog(@"numberString = %@",numberString);
```

output

```
[Currency.m:64] self.amountFormat = ##,##0.00
[Currency.m:73] numberString = 1 533 434,34
```

change your settings under general - international - region format to South Africa if you wish to test

Comment: Show all of the relevant code for setting up the number formatter and converting a number to a string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As for formatting string, `,` means `grouping separator` and `.` means `decimal separator` which specified by the locale, **NOT literal character**. See [the format specification](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-numbers.html#Number_Format_Patterns).
To override that, you must specify the locale that `grouping separator` is `,` and `decimal separator` is `.` like `en_US_POSIX`

```
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

OR manually specify `grouping separator` and `decimal separator` like:

```
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
```

Answer (score 0):

As [rintaro answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25326717/468724) suggest you have to add `grouping separator` and `decimal separator`

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setPositiveFormat:@"#,##0.00"];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","]; //This line taken from above answer
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."]; //This line taken from above answer
[formatter setLenient:YES];
NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:@123414231412.45];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Console output

```
2014-08-15 11:28:59.075 TestApp[700:60b] 123,414,231,412.45
```

Comment: unfortunately it still doesnt seem to work, did you try change your region to South Africa under general - international - region format?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString *)amount:(NSString *)val{
    NSNumber *someNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[val doubleValue]];
    NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    // if you want to add the  custom currency than you need to specify otherwise it will take the $ USD currency. here you have to pass the string with valid string amount without ex: 135.21 (Valid), 13,2000.00 (Invalid), $123 (Invalid).
    return  [nf stringFromNumber:someNumber];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.